# ¿Cómo poner nombre personalizado a sitios en local host?

Tags: php, windows, wamp

¿Cómo pongo un nombre personalizado a un sitio o aplicación en localhost?

Por ejemplo: si tengo la ruta `http://localhost:8080/mi-sitio` cómo puedo acceder a este desde `misitio.dev`.

Se que se pueden añadir dominios en el archivo `host` del sistema para crear este tipo de nombres personalizados pero no logro que funcione de esta forma:

```
# Archivo host
# Mi sitio personalizado
http://localhost:8080/mi-sitio    mi-sitio.dev
```

Comment: Creo que tienes mal la sintáxis del fichero hosts de windows (https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) es "IP dominio" por lo tanto sería: 127.0.0.1 mi-sitio.dev pero por otro lado, tendrías que configurar apache con virtualhost tal como te sugiere OscarR

Comment: @track3r pero eso no lo tiene que hacer en cada pc?

Comment: Si claro, dada la pregunta se deduce que quiere acceder a su sitio desde su propio ordenador pero con el dominio mi-sitio.dev, de ahí mi comentario. Si quisiera acceder desde otros ordenadores necesitaría un servidor de nombres para que el resto resolviera adecuadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Hace bastante que no toco nada *Windows*, pero si no me equivoco, el servidor *Wamp* usa Apache.

El archivo *host* tiene que añadir la ip y después separados por espacios los *ServerName* y *ServerAlias* del *virtualhost*. Ejemplo:

```
127.0.0.1 mi-sitio.dev www.mi-sitio.dev subdominio.mi-sitio.dev
```

Después se debe crear/añadir un *virtualhost* y activarlo en *Apache*.

> Creo que era en el archivo *httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName mi-sitio.dev
    ServerAlias www.mi-sitio.dev subdominio.mi-sitio.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mi-sitio"
        <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mi-sitio">
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Como nota adicional, en mi navegador para acceder al dominio personalizado tengo que añadir la barra / al final del nombre, si no me lo intenta buscar en internet. http://mi-sitio.dev/